# SSIS File Will Only Work 1x

Tags: sql, ssis

I created an SSIS file to add a table to a sql database from a spreadsheet.  I can execute the file 1x and it works.  But when I delete the table and try to recreate it by executing the SSIS file again, it gives me an error that the table already exists.  But it is deleted.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Did you delete the rows on the table or did you drop the table? It is very unclear what is your problem

Comment: Error suggests that table does exist. Are you sure you are looking in the right environment?

Comment: Questions about code that do not supply code are difficult to answer

Comment: Why are you dropping and creating tables in SSIS in the first place? Shouldn't you be deleting records and inserting them?

Comment: After you delete the table, try closing and reopening the SSIS environment.